# Solving radial heat equation with Laplace transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have the following problem:

Solve $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial^2 (ru)}{\partial r^2}, r \le a$ subject to:

$u(r,0)=u_0$ and $\dfrac{1}{k}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r} = u_0 - u(a,t) - t$ at $r=a$

I would like to see how this was solved using the Laplace transform, but am struggling to solve the resulting ODE.

Comment: The resulting ODE should be
$$s \ U(r,s)-u(r,0)=\frac{\partial ^2U(r,s)}{\partial r^2}+\frac{2 \frac{\partial U(r,s)}{\partial r}}{r}$$